# for( … in …) not working with array

Tags: javascript

I'm somehow confused:

I have a list of commands like this:

```
var commands = [{"command": "read"}, {"command": "write"}, {"command": "login"}];
```

If I try it access one of the commands like this it works:

```
console.log(commands[0]["command"]); // Output is "read"
console.log(commands[0].command);    // Output is "read"
```

But if I try this the output is always undefined:

```
for(command in commands)
    console.log(command["command"]); // undefined, undefined, undefined
```

Comment: If your commands variable is json, you could also do this http://jsfiddle.net/aMTTU/

Comment: In spite of some of the answers below, don't `for-in` an Array. It's the wrong tool for the job in JavaScript. A `for` loop or the `forEach` method ensures only numeric indices in a guaranteed order and doesn't block your ability to extend `Array.prototype` if you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `for..in` with an array? Just access by index, and you also avoid potential problems of prototype extensions (see `hasOwnProperty`)

```
var i,len=commands.length;

for (i=0;i<len;i++ ) {
    console.log commands[i].command
}
```

If order does not matter, more concisely

```
for (i=commands.length-1;i>=0;i-- ) {

}
```

Or

```
var i=commands.length;
while (i--) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The `for ... in` construct iterates over the *keys* of the objects in the array, not the objects themselves. So you would need to write:

```
for(index in commands)
    console.log(commands[index]["command"]);
```

Answer (score 9):

`for` does an array iteration in javascript, so you want:

```
for(command in commands)
    console.log(commands[command]["command"]);
```

ie, the `command` variable in your example is an array index, not the enumerated item from the array.

Comment: Addition: you can use functional-style forEach/every/any =)

Comment: @Santiago - I have no idea what you mean, care to elaborate?

Comment: Nono, your answer's perfect! I was addressing the OP. For the behavior he wants, he can use forEach.

Answer (score 3):

The `for (.. in ..)` construct is for looping over objects, not arrays. Since you have an array of objects, you should be doing:

```
for (var i = 0, j = commands.length; i < j; i += 1) {
  console.log(commands[i].command);
}
```

For a thorough explanation as to why you should use this `for` construct instead of the `for...in`, see [answer #3010848](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848).

Comment: Uh, no, he has clearly defined an array of objects that he wishes to iterate: `var commands = [{"command": "read"}, {"command": "write"}, {"command": "login"}];`

Comment: @Martin Actually OP is creating an array of objects.  The array is what is being looped through which is more natural as a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this

```
 for(var x in commands)
      console.log(commands[x].command);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
for(command in commands[0]) {
    console.log(command["command"]);
}
```

Comment: That won't work because `commands[0].command` is the `"read"` string, so `commands[0].command["command"]` will give you `undefined`.